# What are the benefits of using common intermediate language?

Tags: vb.net

Are there any security or non-security benefits to using this? Why do people use CIL? I do not understand why people use common intermediate language.

Answer (score 1):

One reason lies in that word 'common'.  You may be running a vb shop, but want to outsource some coding.  Unfortunately, the only developers available are skilled in C# but don't get all the `dim`s, `sub`s, `let`s etc in VB.  So, they write in C# and compile to CIL (or vice when versa).  Then you can either take the CIL as is, or convert it to VB using the 3rd party tools available.

Comment: _only developers available are skilled in C# but don't get all the dims_ "skilled" developers will start understand and write proper vb.net in the week and vice versa for vb.net developers. Then Visual Studio allow to have both c# and vb.net project under same solution.

Comment: i guess the 'available' developers aren't necessarily the 'skilled' developers.  :-)